# Passing command line switch to Nashorn JavaScript engine

Tags: java, javafx-8, nashorn

I am trying to run the the following code in Java environment using the nashorn.[Code Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/fxamples.html)

```
load("fx:base.js");
load("fx:controls.js");
load("fx:graphics.js");

var material = new PhongMaterial();
material.diffuseColor = Color.LIGHTGREEN;
material.specularColor = Color.rgb(30, 30, 30);

var meshView = Java.to([
    new Box(200, 200, 200),
    new Sphere(100),
    new Cylinder(100, 200)
], "javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D[]");

for (var i = 0; i != 3; i++) {
    meshView[i].material = material;
    meshView[i].translateX = (i + 1) * 220;
    meshView[i].translateY = 200;
    meshView[i].translateZ = 20;
    meshView[i].drawMode = DrawMode.FILL;
    meshView[i].cullFace = CullFace.BACK;
};

var pointLight = new PointLight(Color.WHITE);
pointLight.translateX = 800;
pointLight.translateY = -200;
pointLight.translateZ = -1000;

var root = new Group(meshView);
root.children.add(pointLight);

var scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400, true);
scene.fill = Color.rgb(127, 127, 127);
scene.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
$STAGE.scene = scene;
$STAGE.show();
```

It uses JavaScript APIs to create a JavaFx scene.

If you use the `jjs` command line utility with `-fx` switch it works as expected, but if you execute the same file with nashorn script engine via Java code, it throws the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.findClass(Context.java:983)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.simpleType(NativeJava.java:489)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.type(NativeJava.java:320)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.type(NativeJava.java:312)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.type(NativeJava.java:308)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$3$500A$\=fx\!base.LOAD_FX_CLASSES(fx:base.js:38)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$4$\=fx\!controls.:program(fx:controls.js:30)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:636)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:229)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:387)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.evaluateSource(Context.java:1150)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.load(Context.java:799)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.load(Global.java:995)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:2)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:636)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:229)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:387)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:437)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:401)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:397)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:147)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:212)
    at com.metalop.nashorn.javafx.GettingStarted.main(GettingStarted.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:512)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:87)
    ... 25 more
```

So how do I pass the `-fx` switch or initilize javafx within java code for nashorn?

Comment: I believe the critical part is the root `IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized` exception. This means you are running JavaFX code without having started JavaFX (what the `javafx.application.Application` does). So one solution should be to run your java application with a `javafx.application.Application`, not just any `Main` class.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: Extending the class from Application did load the dependencies and solve the problem. Thanks for the comment...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things that I did to get the JavaScript working as passing the `-fx` nashorn arg didn't work for me.

1. As mentioned in the comment by Nikos the class has to extend from `javafx.application.‌​Application` and the main function should then call the `launch()` which has the code for Nashorn initialization and JS script execution.
2. The start method has `start(Stage primaryStage)` signature. The `Stage` object had to be bound to the JavaScript while evaluating.

The following code is a sample how I was able to achieve it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.SimpleBindings;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GettingStarted extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

        try (InputStream is = GettingStarted.class.getResourceAsStream("getting-started.js")) {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
            bindings.put("$STAGE", primaryStage);
            engine.eval(reader, bindings);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your Nashorn engine with `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory`. It has overloads of `getScriptEngine` that take an array of Strings – those are the command line arguments.

Unfortunately, you can't do this through `javax.script` interface, but `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting` is also a public and supported API.

Comment: I tried using `NashornScriptEngineFactory` and passing the `-fx`parameter, but it didn't work. Your pointers were helpful and informative though, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Attila mentioned, no way to pass arguments via javax.script. You've two options:

(1) Use Nashorn specific API -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngineFactory.html

(or)

(2) Define "nashorn.args" system property in your java command line.

See also: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes

In either case, I'm not sure the particular option in case, "-fx" would work. This is because FX code has specific initialization requirements which are taken care of "jjs" tool. Not sure if that will work in script engine
embedding mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I quickly tried it but `-fx` arg didn't work here.